# java.lang.RuntimeException in react native app

Tags: android, react-native

This is a stack trace from crashlytics in my react native app, it happens quite often and is the top crash by volume by far.

I'm not really sure where to begin investigating this? Does anyone have any ideas?

This happens on Android, using react native 0.55

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error invoking callback 520
       at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(NativeRunnable.java)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:29)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
       at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$3.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:192)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

Caused by com.facebook.jni.CppException: Failed to create Value from JSON: 
       at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(NativeRunnable.java)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:29)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
       at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$3.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:192)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using fetch() and then doing response.json() when the server sends
malformed JSON causes a crash.Use axios as web client to call api.
If you are using `react-native-fetch-blob` and `react-native-cached-image` then also this error occur as fetch-blob using fecth() method.